# Re loading integers into an array

Tags: c, malloc

The code below works fine when M <= 4, but seems to bugger up if you put in a whole number that's any bigger (in this case, I actually need M to be 10). Does anyone know why this is happening and what can be done about it? Thanks.

```
/*
"Read all 100 numbers from the text file and store it in a 10x10 array."
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *fptr;
int n;
int M = 4; // Length and width of array

int main()
{
    // Allocating memory
    int **myArray = (int **)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
 
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        myArray[j] = (int *)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
    }

    // Loading data into array
    fptr = fopen("List of Numbers.txt","r");
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            fscanf(fptr,"%d",&n);
            // printf("%d ",n);
            myArray[i][j] = n;
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);

    // Printing
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf("%d ",myArray[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C, not C++.  I have retagged it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
int **myArray = (int **)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
```

should be:

```
int **myArray = (int **)malloc(M * sizeof(int *));
                                              ^
```

You are allocating an array of pointers, not an array of `int`s.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Just out of curiosity, would you care to explain why my original code didn't work on a hardware level? I would presume it's something to do with the fact that an int is 4 bytes while an int* is 8 bytes, yes?

Comment: Yes, precisely so, assuming it is a 64 bit build.